# My value in my Blazor Server side's razor page is not updating when I call a scoped service repeatedly, that is outputting the value. Why?

Tags: service, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

I have following razor.cs code that is calling a function in a scoped service. The function in the scoped service is reading a dynamic changing process value from a rest API . When I call the function in my razor.cs page once I can read the value without problem.

When I call the function repeatedly (cyclic): I see that the value is correctly changing each time in the service function (from the log).
But the value on the razor page is showing just the first read value, and is not actualized on the next function calls. What could be wrong?

My razor page code:

```
 <table>
   <tr>                    
     <td >Process item</td>
     <td >@value_screen</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

My razor.cs code:

```
 public string value_screen=""; 
 public async Task Read_value_from_scoped_service()
 {
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
   value_screen = await Task.Run(() => Service_API.Read_Process_value(url));
   StateHasChanged();         
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
 }
```

my function in the scoped service (Service_API) :

```
 public string value_from_API="";
 public string Read_Process_value(string url)
 {
   // some code that delivers the value from a API
     using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logpath))
     {
       sw.WriteLine("item_valuer= " + value_screen + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
       // in the logfile i can see the updated 10 values for each call
     }
   return value_from_API;
 }
```

Comment: Simple sanity check since .net8 blazor : is this particular page in interactive mode ?
Because the behaviour you are describing is consistent with a streaming or static page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from you code how what you've actually shown plugs together.

Here's a demo that I wrote for someone else that I think provides a template for you to use.

This is the my data provider.  It's not a service because it doesn't need to be.

```cs
public class WeatherGaugeProvider
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<int> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    private WeatherGaugeProvider() { }

    public static  Task<int> GetTemperatureAsync()
    {
        var gauge = new WeatherGaugeProvider();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            // Your code to get the data
            // this just emulates that
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            gauge._tcs.SetResult(Random.Shared.Next(-40, 60));
        });
        return gauge._tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

My Home page uses a timer to get the data every second.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<div class="mb-3">
    <button disabled="@_isRunning" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.GetDataAsync">Get Values</button>
    <button disabled="@(!_isRunning)" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.StopTimer">Stop</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Temperature : @_temperature</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private int _temperature;
    private Timer? _timer;
    private bool _isRunning => _timer is not null;

    private Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        _timer = new(OnTimerElasped, null, 0, 1000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
    }

    private async void OnTimerElasped(object? state)
    {
        _temperature = await WeatherGaugeProvider.GetTemperatureAsync();
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```